# What is the difference between a shared folder and a virtual folder?

Tags: iis

I am working with my friends on a web application hosted with IIS (Internet Information Service).  I noticed that there're some so-called virtual folders in the IIS website tree view, and still some shared folders are used in our web application.

The virtual folders are like this:

```
http://myserver/folder1
```

The shared folders are like this:

```
\\myserver\folder2
```

So, what's the difference between them?

Many thanks.

## Add - 1 -

And what's the difference between a web application and a virtual folder? I often right click on a virtual folder and turn it into a web application. ***But I just don't know what this action actually means?!*** Could anyone show me some material addressing in detail how a web application in IIS is invoked? I hope it could fit in the following chain.

a HTTP text request (GET, PUT, etc) arrives at IIS ->  ***What happens here?*** -> a HTTP text response leave the IIS

Comment: They are entirely different things. The former is a resource served by a web server; the latter is a network share usually available through the local network only. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_share I think to get more detailed info, you need to clarify where those shared folders are being used exactly

Comment: I feel I am not quite sure about some concepts during web development, my question is just one of them. So could anyone recommend some materials which address concepts like that?

Comment: I want to start a bounty, but the start bounty button is not shown yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtual folders are folders relatively to an URL path. It means that, as `http://myserver` is the root folder, you can **map** a physical folder on your disk drive into a folder that is *virtually* child of `myserver` wherever `http://myserver` is mapped to.

Shared folders are relative to the SMB protocol. The difference between HTTP and SMB is that with HTTP you can host a web application (ie. run code and generate HTML output) but with SMB you can only share files *statically*, ie. you can share executable files but they must be first downloaded and then executed.